# Onto Function and Range/Codomain

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the range have to equal the whole codomain for a function to be onto, or is it simply that the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb R^m$?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a function is onto (or surjective) if and only if its range equals its codomain.

If the function is a linear mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ which is represented by a matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, this is the case if and only if the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb R^m$.